# How to check database for day of the week when format is in m/d/y?

Tags: php, sql, date

My database has a bunch of dates in the format 3/21/2015 and I need to find when one is monday or tuesday etc...

an example query I need is  SELECT Date FROM Tablename WHERE date = monday.
I want results that are all on a certain monday.

With that i tried using the code :

```
 $monday = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("last monday"));
```

not sure how to incorporate the php with the sql

Comment: Well you can format your date to the database format e.g. `$monday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("last monday"));` or transform the date in the database to one that suits you... e.g. UNIX time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date is not real date so in mysql you need to convert it to a real date using the `str_to_time` function and using `dayname` function you can do the comparison.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname

```
mysql> select DAYNAME(str_to_date('3/21/2015','%m/%d/%Y')) as day_name ;
+----------+
| day_name |
+----------+
| Saturday |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

So the select query goes as

```
 SELECT Date FROM Tablename 
 WHERE DAYNAME(str_to_date(date,'%m/%d/%Y')) = 'Monday'
```